# afterRender in Lightning component not called (EDIT: when the .app has it's own afterRender function.)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to implement the accepted answer given here

[Including SVG in a Lightning Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77459/including-svg-in-a-lightning-component)

which uses afterRender to change the component's DOM.

Except for me, I cannot get afterRender to get called.

My code in the *component*Renderer.js file is

```
({
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
     alert('d');
       debugger;
}
 })
```

but nothing happens.

I changed the function name to render, eg.

```
render: function(component, helper) {
```

and that IS called.

So what could I possibly be doing wrong?  There's nothing in the JS console.

Thanks

UPDATE: it **is** called if I remove the afterRender that I have in the containing .app.  Smells like a bug in SF.  Fortunately for me I can live without the afterRender in the .app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call the this.superAfterRender(); in your afterRender call.

Answer (score 6):

In case this helps anyone else:

afterRender has to go in the Renderer of your lightning component, not the Controller or Helper.

Comment: Very well spotted. A renderer file is part of the component bundle and is auto-wired if you follow the naming convention, <componentName>Renderer.js. For example, the renderer for `sample.cmp` would be in `sampleRenderer.js`