# SLDS classes issues

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, slds

I am working on design using SLDS classes , I am using **Discussion Feed** [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/publishers/#flavor-discussion-feed-publisher-feed-active) is the link . The icons for attach file and add user are not working. What am I missing .

Comment: Please add your code here

Comment: The code is already there in link . Standard SLDS Doc

Comment: Have you added a Static Resource?

Comment: Yes , I have imported the resource using <apex:slds /> tag and wrapperd the code under <div class="slds-scope">...code </div> The UI renders correctly . But the publisher items are not working .

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? The  tag has numerous browser compatibility issues- I've seen the orientation break for icons when two SLDS icons are included in the same parent container. Chrome/Firefox. The  tag also flat out doesn't work in IE11.

Would suggest converting the SVGs into static images or icon fonts, then using that instead of the pants-on-head SLDS approach that seems to have been taken because [Lightning doesn't support the use of SVG tags](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/77459/including-svg-in-a-lightning-component)